# KeyListener starts listening only after Button is clicked

Tags: java, swt

Currently I am trying to integrate MKYong's [KeyListener example](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/swt-how-to-capture-keyboard-event/) into an Eclipse RCP app.

I'm getting some weird behavior from a `Button` I am registering the `KeyListener` to, it only starts listening to keyboard input after the button was clicked the first time.

I would like it to listen to all keyboard events occurred after it was created. To me it is irrelevant what sort of SWT `Control` I would have to use.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A control only gets key events when it has the keyboard focus.

If you want to get all key events you can use the `addFilter` method of `Display`

```java
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
   public void handleEvent(Event event)
   {
     // Handle key down event
   }
});
```

Comment: Just remember to remove that filter when you're done listening, otherwise your whole app will be buggy.

Answer (score 1):

You've added KeyListener to Button. Button is notified of keyEvent when it got focus. If you want to listen for keyboard events in your whole window then add KeyListener to your shell:

```
shell.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()...
```

If you want global KeyListener add display filter:

```
Listener listener = new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if(e.type == SWT.KeyDown||e.type == SWT.KeyUp) {
            System.out.println("" + e.keyCode);
        }
    }
};
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyUp, listener);
```